# ActiveRecord specific select doesn't bring paperclip url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip with S3 to store files and some images the user inputs through an application, however, when I try to retrieve that url  using specific selects it always bring the missing file, here is my code to illustrate the problem:

```
class UploadedFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file
  attr_accessor :file_url

  def file_url
    self.file.url(:original) if self.file
  end
end

UploadedFile.first.as_json(methods: [:file_url]) #Will work and will show the url in the json

UploadedFile.all.as_json(methods: [:file_url]) #Will work and will show the url in the json

UploadedFile.select('id', 'othertablecolumn').joins("JOINS SOMETING").where("SOME CONDITIONS").as_json(methods: [:file_url]) #Will not work and will show the missing url in the json
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Paperclip url generator it seems to be I have to select all of the fields that the file stores in the database (file_name, file_size, file_updated_at, file_content_type):

```
:hash_data=>":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:updated_at
```

and it will be able to build the entire URL.